# Problems on installing Laravel Composer dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

We are trying to install the package google / recaptcha 1.1 through Composer, in order to install it Composer asks us to install the phpdocumentor package, however when running

```
# composer require --dev phpdocumentor / phpdocumentor dev-master
```

this gives us an error, about which I attach a screen print. [image]

Previously to the current state Composer had indicated us a problem with nikic / php-parser package, we found that package listed in the file composer.lock and we removed it, however now composer gives us this error relative to the package symfony / console v4.1.1 that also it is listed in the composer.lock file, we also try to remove this dependency from the composer.lock, but I am not sure that we are doing things right by eliminating these dependencies. Because in addition to deleting one another error is indicated on another package and if we continue like this we would end up eliminating many dependencies. Please help!

Comment: Why you trying to install dev-master instead of current version?

Answer (score 2):

**don't manually remove stuff from composer.lock**

When you require packages without passing a specific version (like dev-master, or ^1) composer will download the latest versions respecting your composer.json and record those versions on composer.lock.

composer.lock is nothing but a byproduct of composer install

If you manually edit composer.lock, you are basically messing up composers internals.

The correct way to remove a package is either running `composer remove vendor/package`
or manually removing it from **composer.json** and then running `composer update`

composer.lock is sacred, don't touch it.

Now you've touched it and you want to unscrew yourself, so:

- remove composer.lock `rm composer.lock`
- install your libraries back, and get an untampered composer.lock `composer install`
- install your lib `composer require --dev phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor dev-master`

Same results, different approach:

- remove composer.lock `rm composer.lock`
- update composer.json with your desired libraries (add the phpdocumentor to the dev dependencies section on composer.json)
- install everything again `composer install`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Before edit composer.lock we got a backup of this file. What about restoring this backup? Doing this can we go to the initial configuration?

Comment: TLDR: Yes. One more idea: since composer.lock job is to keep the minor versions of the libs you declared on compose.json, get the versions composer.lock stored and update your composer.json with them. remove everythin (composer.lock and vendor) then reinstall

Answer (score 0):

PhpDocumentor you are trying to install requires `phpDocumentor/Reflection` who requires `nikic/php-parser` and this version is to high for your other dependencies.

use `composer depends nikic/php-parser` to understrand what's wrong.